# SQL - after sorting, return only rows with certain consecutive values in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have columns `name, timestamp, doing`. I've already sorted by `name`, then by `timestamp`, and I expect that moving down the `doing` column within a group with the same `name` looks like `A, A, A, B, B, A, A, ...` - alternating series of `A` and `B`. I need to get only the rows which comprise the first `B` row after a transition from `A` to `B` **within a group with the same name**.

```
name timestamp doing
1    1         A
1    2         A
1    3         B
1    4         B
1    5         A
2    2         B
2    4         A
2    6         B
2    8         A
```

I would like to return

```
name timestamp doing
1    3         B
2    6         B
```

But **not**

```
2    2         B
```

because it is not a transition from `A` to `B` within `name = 2`

Comment: please tag the dbms being used.

Comment: what type of sql is this?

Comment: Sorry for the oversight - postgresql, just updated the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(doing) over (partition by name order by timestamp) as prev_doing
      from t
     ) t
where prev_doing = 'A' and doing = 'B';
```

Comment: This solved my problem, and lead me to find the follow-up (dual) answer of the `lead` function to find all the rows which constitute the last `B` before a transition to `A`